# Aggregate efficient production and division of labour

Tags: microeconomics

How to resolve the following seeming contradiction? Mas-Colell, Whinston, Green p. 148 Prop. 5.E.1 says that the efficient aggregate (coordinated) production is just the sum of individually optimal productions. But Adam Smith argued that [division of labour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_of_labour) allows more efficient production than the sum of individual productions.

Of course Adam Smith's argument is informal, so it is not clear what assumptions differ from Mas-Colell. It could be that Smith envisioned production units with market power, externalities or some other inefficiency and the inefficiency somehow disappears with aggregation.

Comment: It seems to me Xiaokai Yang's inframarginal analysis(with) is related to what's on your mind. Maybe I got it wrong and not sure whether it's worth mentioning, because of the controversy on his approach. https://ideas.repec.org/e/pya130.html

Answer (score 1):

I would say, it is more Proposition $5.\text{F}.1$ on page 150, *in combination* with $5.\text{E}.1$ that leads to, as the authors write discussing the two,

> *"...if a collection of firms each independently maximizes profits with respect to the same fixed price vector $p >>0$, then the aggregate
>   production is socially efficient. That is, there is no other production plan for the economy as a whole that could produce more output using no additional inputs."*

Note that no assumption of identical suppliers is made here, or any other restrictive assumption about technology or the production set. The crucial assumption is the "price-taking" behavior assumed for all firms. Or, "no-market-power". Or, **"all firms are equal":** **doesn't Perfect Competition sound *a lot* like the market version of Communism (not Socialism)?**

P.S.: Externalities could also create issues here, of course.